# how to automate printing or downloading of PDFs in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to print or download as PDF the latest 4 sheets in Google Sheets to PDF. But I am getting a getLastUpdated is not a function error. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
function downloadLatest4SheetsAsPDF() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get all the sheets in the spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // Sort the sheets by date updated
  sheets.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.getParent().getLastUpdated().getTime() - a.getParent().getLastUpdated().getTime();
  });
  // Get the latest 4 sheets
  var latestSheets = sheets.slice(0, 4);
  // Loop through the latest 4 sheets
  for (var i = 0; i < latestSheets.length; i++) {
    // Get the current sheet
    var sheet = latestSheets[i];
    // Get the name of the current sheet
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    // Get the PDF blob of the current sheet
    var pdfBlob = sheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    // Save the PDF to Google Drive
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1I3VMLALdtTa_pIfVw9UKpZK3A4OCjL2M');
    folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(sheetName + '.pdf'));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `how to automate printing or downloading of PDFs in google script`, I thought that `automate printing PDFs` and `automate  downloading PDFs` are largely different. And, what does `downloading` you expect mean? And, what does `the latest 4 sheets in Google Sheets` mean? Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike in Google Sheets, downloading as a PDF and printing as PDF seems to do the same thing: you get a PDF file of a sheet. Last 4 sheets means that if I have multiple Sheets (aka tabs) in the file, I only need to print the last 4 in terms of date created. I hope that clarifies it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to export the Spreadsheet to Google Drive in a PDF format. But, I cannot still understand about `the latest 4 sheets in Google Sheets` from `I only need to print the last 4 in terms of date created.`. I apologize for my poor English skill again. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike ok imagine you have a Google Sheet file with 20 tabs. Each tab is created at a different time. Let's say the 1st tab you created a year ago and the 20th tab you created yesterday. The script should sort the tabs according to creation date and just print the 4 tabs that were created the latest. So if tab 20 was created yesterday, tab 19 created the day before yesterday and so on, it should print the tabs that were created the latest. Not sure how else I can explain that but I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to retrieve the latest 4 sheets (in order of the tab created date.) from a Google Spreadsheet, in your situation, how can we know the date that the tab is created?

Comment: @Tanaike this line "sheets.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.getParent().getLastUpdated().getTime() - a.getParent().getLastUpdated().getTime();"

Comment: Spreadsheet Class has no getLastUpdated() method

Comment: You could use the id of the spreadsheet to get the date the file was last updated but that has no information about which sheets were updated.  There might be something in revisions.  I don't use revisions much so I don't really know. I'd guess you'll have to keep the date on each sheet yourself in order to do that.